# secure communication between two application same signature app or different signature app

Tags: android, security

I have two Android apps, App A and App B.

Those two have to communicate with each other in a secure manner. I defined a custom permission for that in App A. App B uses that custom permission. If I set protectionLevel to "normal" than this works fine, but that does not seem really secure, as anyone could just use that permission.

The only way that this would be really secure is, if I could set protectionLevel to signature. Sadly I have the following restrictions:

```
App A has to be signed with Cert A
App B has to be signed with Cert B
App B could also be signed with Cert A (means A and B) but that does not seem to get me anywhere, also according to this source
```

Is there any way to get this to work? And if not (which I guess is the case):

What is a good way to make sure that only App B can communicate with App A?

can you please give the complete code of this application ???
because in my code there r some mistake in broadcast reciever. so plzz give me the complete code for this problem